# Let $A = \{1, 3, 5, 15, 18\}$ and $R$ be defined by $xRy$ if and only if $x\vert y$. create a diagraph and hasse diagram.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The title is the question, to be honest I have never seen this type of notation $x\vert y$ for determining the values. For instance, usually my instructor would say in the homework "if and only if $x^2 + y^2 = 0$" or some such other thing that would allow you to test values. This notation "$\vert$" I am not familiar with. I have tried emailing the professor but I haven't received a response.

Comment: It means "divides".  Thus $3\,|\,15$ since $3\times 5 = 15$.

Comment: $x\mid y$ means that $x$ is a factor of $y$, or alternatively that $y$ is a multiple of $x$.

Comment: $x|y$ means "$x$ divides $y$", or equivalently "$y$ is divisible by $x$".

Comment: thanks a lot guys, I was not having much luck on the internet finding that.